error 70 while copying a file with fso.copyfile
I have this little bit of code I would like to use to copy a text file in the same directory as the workbook. the file fullname I want to copy is stored in the cell B14 Cells(14, 2).Valueand I get the local folder's path with Application.ThisWorkBook.path
Sub copy_to_local()
    Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = twb.Worksheets(1)
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fs.CopyFile tws.Cells(14, 2).Value, Application.ThisWorkbook.path, True
End Sub

I double checked with MsgBox if the path and full name were correct and they are. I tryed in another disc and still had the same issue. The path of both the file I want to copy and where to copy are on a server so it might play, but I can use fs.CreateTextFile in the same directory I want to paste. I also tried to add a "" at the en of the paste destination and got an error 59. I also tried to put "./" in the paste destination and it runned without error, but also without pasting the file.

Error 70 is "Permission denied". If you have permissions to write into that folder, maybe the file itself already exists and is locked.

the file doesn't exist already, it's empty at first, and then when I call it again, it should overwrite the already existing file. But rn it's empty

I tried to use fs.Createfile with the fullname (path\test.txt) and it worked fine. I also tried with ./test.txt and it run without error but doesn't create the file or create somewhere I don't know

./test.txt will create a file in the CWD (current working directory) which is a term from good old MS-DOS times - you shouldn't rely on that, same is true when using ./ as destination for the copyFile. When you can create an empty file first and later get the error, I would assume that you don't close the empty file and therefore it is locked. Can you manually delete it (using Explorer or CMD-prompt)? Also, why do you create an empty file first if it is overwritten anyhow?

MS documentation for CopyFile method of FileSystemObject shows:
If source contains wildcard characters, or destination ends with a path separator (**), it is assumed that destination is an existing folder in which to copy matching files. Otherwise, destination is assumed to be the name of a file to create. In either case, three things can happen when an individual file is copied:
If destination does not exist, source gets copied. This is the usual case.
If destination is an existing file, an error occurs if overwrite is False. Otherwise, an attempt is made to copy source over the existing file.
If destination is a directory, an error occurs.
In your case, the destination is a folder (the path of the workbook), so the method assumes that you want to copy your file overwriting the folder where your workbook is located.
Just add a backslash to the destination folder name, and it should work as you intended:
 fs.CopyFile tws.Cells(14, 2).Value, Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\", True


What I used that worked for me is I created an empty file then copied the text from the source in the empty file. It is not the greatest way of doing it but at least it works.
Private Sub CpFile(path As String)
    ' 
    '
    '
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim src As TextStream
    Dim nfile As TextStream

    Set src = fs.opentextfile(path)
    Dim filename As String
    tmp = Split(path, "\")
    filename = tmp(UBound(tmp))
    Set nfile = fs.CreateTextFile(Application.ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & filename, True)
    nfile.WriteLine (src.readall)

    nfile.Close
    Set nfile = Nothing
    src.Close
    Set src = Nothing
    Set fs = Nothing
End Sub

